# field in email table is deleted when foreign key constraint is added to it

Tags: mysql

I have created a database with two tables in MySQL.
The code can be seen below:

```sql
create table user_information (
Login_id varchar(50),
User_id varchar(50),
Surname varchar(50),
forename varchar(50),
title varchar(
position varchar(50),
phone varchar(25),
email varchar(25),
location varchar(25)
);
```

```sql
insert into email (User_id, email)
values ("202012345", "B.C.Tompsett@hull.ac.uk"),
("20190408", "J.Reckitt@example.com"),
("20070909", "T.Clark@example.com"),
("20070910", "B.Dark@example.com"),
("20232609", "S.Cliff@example.com"),
("20201231", "Dan.Doe@example.com"),
("201604403", "TCook@example.com"),
("201704423", "JClark@example.com"),
("201204373","B.Walker@example.com" );

SELECT * from email
```

I have also added the foreign key in the code below:

```sql
alter table email
add constraint fk_User_id
FOREIGN KEY(User_id) REFERENCES user_information(User_id);
```

## **The problem I am facing**

The problem I have is when I try to delete a field in the email table to see if the foreign key constraint works but the constraint does not work.

The error message I suppose to get is Error Code 1451: cannot delete or update a parent row

I tried looking at the creation of the foreign key to see if there were any errors but I can't find any to my knowledge.

I also tried to remove the data in the email table and insert the data again to see if that makes many difference but it unfortunately did not.

Comment: what 'field' ? can you supply the sql statement you are issuing and the error message if any you receive?

Comment: Your understanding of foreign keys appears to be back-to-front - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/076kVQID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why it is not working :**

> - Your email table should be your parent table
> - You did not specify any `ON DELETE` in your `add constraint` although mysql assign a default

**How we can solve:**

> - update email table schema with a primary key
>
>   create table email
>   (
>   User_id varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
>   email   varchar(50) null
>   );
> - delete your old constrain and add below one, with `ON DELETE RESTRICT` it will show `[23000][1451] Cannot delete or update a parent row` while try to
>   delete row form parent (email) table which have foreign key in
>   user_information table
>
>   ALTER TABLE user_information
>   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tblEmail_User_id
>   FOREIGN KEY (User_id)
>   REFERENCES email (User_id)
>   ON DELETE RESTRICT;

**Please have a look at attached screen shot**

[image]

Comment: So if i delete a row it won't let me?

Comment: @Dan, good day, thank u for comment, u can delete row from user_information but not from emai. If there is no ref in user_information for an email then only that email row can delete